# Clockdiff: host is down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I have two computers in a Campus Network. They can ping each other. I can use `ssh` to connect one using the other one, but when I use `clockdiff` both show `host is down`. Is there any thing wrong?

System is ubuntu 20.04, 5.4.0-42-generic

```
xgb@initiator:~$ ping 10.16.108.229
PING 10.16.108.229 (10.16.108.229) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.16.108.229: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=0.381 ms
64 bytes from 10.16.108.229: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=0.591 ms
64 bytes from 10.16.108.229: icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=0.589 ms

--- 10.16.108.229 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2035ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.381/0.520/0.591/0.098 ms
xgb@initiator:~$ sudo clockdiff 10.16.108.229
............................clockdiff: 10.16.108.229 is down
```

Comment: Have you tried "clockdiff -o' (lower-case Oh) in case the other host is unable to, or configured not to respond to anything other than ICMP ECHO requests? Have you checked with your campus network engineers to see if the network is blocking/firewalling the request?

Comment: Thank you.I have tried '-o' and '-o1' options, they don't work.emmm....I don't know how to contact with our campus network engineer.But I don't think the problem is caused by the campus network maybe.because I have a cloud server, I can use clockdiff to it.the result is okay.

Comment: I found one computer has an ufw, I check both of the computers, I close ufw. then sometime computerA can successfully clockdiff computerB,sometime not.but computerB can never clockdiff computerA.